# get global value in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net, session, global-asax

i have a problem about `global.asax`, in file `global.asax` i want to get variable session which i already set session in `login.aspx` and while i get variable session, its error : **Object reference not set to an instance of an object**

code for `global.asax` :

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string SID = Cookies.GetCookie().SessionID; // error at this point
     if (ShoppingCart.CheckIsSessionActive() == false)
     {
         Cookies.DeleteCookie();
         FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
                Response.Redirect("../expired.htm");
     }
}
```

code setting session in `login.aspx.cs`

```
  protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();

      var sess = Cryptography.SetSID();

      Cookies cookies = new Cookies();
      cookies.UserID = (int)row["Id"];
      cookies.UserName = txtLoginID.Text;
      cookies.SessionID = sess;

      Cookies.SetCookie(cookies);

      Response.Redirect("~/Admin/Lounge.aspx");
  }
```

but if i disabled code for `global.asax` and direct to file `lounge.aspx`, and in file `Lounge.aspx.cs` get value like in file `global.asax` its working

code for `lounge.aspx.cs` :

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        int UserID = Cookies.GetCookie().UserID;
        string SID = Cookies.GetCookie().SessionID;
  }
```

code for function GetCookie() :

```
  public static Cookies GetCookie()
    {
        Cookies cookies = Cache.Get("Cookie" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) as Cookies;

        if (cookies == null)
        {
            cookies = GetCookieToCache();
            Cache.Insert("Cookie" + HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, cookies, 15);
        }

        return cookies;
    }

    private static Cookies GetCookieToCache()
    {
        Cookies cookies = new Cookies();
        HttpCookie HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[COOKIESNAME];

        if (HttpCookie != null)
        {
            Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
            HMB.Components.Utility.DecodeParameters(HttpCookie.Value, out hTable);

            cookies.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Cryptography.TDESDecrypt(hTable["1"].ToString()));
            cookies.UserName = Cryptography.TDESDecrypt(hTable["2"].ToString());
            cookies.SessionID = Cryptography.TDESDecrypt(hTable["3"].ToString());

        }


        return cookies;
    }
```

thx

Comment: have you tried getting/setting `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies`?

Comment: if you see function GetCookie(), in inside function GetCookie() is already setting HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies, i will edit code to show inside function GetCookie